# Change jQuery Datatables Buttons language

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I'm using the very splendid jQuery Datatables control on my MVC razor web page.  The internationalization works well but doesn't include the buttons text.
so my script is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#resultsTable').dataTable({
        dom: 'frtiBp',
        "language": {
            "url": "@ResourceHelper.GetResourceValue(ResourceKeys.DATATABLE_LANG_FILE)"
        },
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
        ]
    });
});
```

The ResourceHelper will get a file as the url like
Common/DataTables/1.10.10/plugins/i18n/English.json
or
Common/DataTables/1.10.10/plugins/i18n/Chinese.json

depending on the language

I can put the strings in for the buttons text from my resources helper

```
        "language": {
            "url": "@ResourceHelper.GetResourceValue(ResourceKeys.DATATABLE_LANG_FILE)",
            "buttons": {
                copy: '@ResourceHelper.GetResourceValue(ResourceKeys.COPY)',
                csv: '@ResourceHelper.GetResourceValue(ResourceKeys.SAVECSV)',
                excel: '@ResourceHelper.GetResourceValue(ResourceKeys.SAVE_EXCEL)'
            }
        },
```

These resolve to the correct values, but I'd kind of like to have all the table language stuff in one place in the DataTables language files, rather than split between my resources files and the datatables ones. I've got them locally so I can edit them but is it possible?  Or is there another way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be a compilation issue of Resources when you use like in this case as string in JS.
One possible way is to make a javascript service for Resources. In our case we used angularjs but the same applies even if you dont use angularjs.

**1. Add a MVC Controller that returns that Resources listed by Key and Value**

***TranslateResourcesController.cs***

```
public class TranslateResourcesController : Controller
{
    // GET: TranslateResources
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        return Json(Resources.Resource.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false, true).Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Value), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**2. Add a .js file (Service)**

```js
(function ()
{
    "use strict";
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);

    function TranslateResourcesService(restangular)
    {
        //Call .cs controller (same could be done using ajax or $http)
       var controllerName = "TranslateResources";
       var url = window.applicationBaseFullUrl + controllerName;
       var service = restangular.oneUrl(controllerName, url).get().$object;
       return service;
    }
    mainApp.factory("TranslateResourcesService", ["Restangular", TranslateResourcesService]);

    function TranslateResourcesController($scope, TranslateResourcesService)
    {
        $scope.TranslateResourcesService = TranslateResourcesService;
    }

    mainApp.controller("TranslateResourcesController", ["$scope", "TranslateResourcesService", TranslateResourcesController]);


})();
```

---

Use now the JS service, or in this case I assigned to an angularjs controller to use it globally.

---

Usage:

```html
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">{{TranslateResourcesService.COPY_BUTTON}}</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but my ResourceHelper works fine, I was just wondering how to get datatables to load the buttons text from the lang file.  I suppose it's a bit confusing as I'm using the resourceHelper for two jobs, I'll edit the question.